# Magento banner slider not showing in localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, ce-1.9.2.4, slider

I am using a ModulesGarden theme Crystal and I can't get the banner slider to show in CMS homepage.

I've tried this:

```
<block type="core/template" name="home_banner" template="page/baners.phtml"/>

<block type="core/template" name="baners" template="page/baners.phtml" home_banner="1"/>
```

but it doesn't show still. I corrected the Permissions for Magento 1.9.2.4.

Any suggestions? I contacted the developers but they haven't gotten back to me.

Comment: Have You applied security patch ?

Comment: Please make sure the banner block is allowed in `system >> permissions >> blocks`

Comment: In which file you have coded?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Lets Do Different Way.
Create New Block like "Slider" and put the slider code in the "Slider Block".

After Creating Block Paste the following code in "header.phtml" (which is located at
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\header.phtml).

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('slider')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: @gravvy : Tried My Answer? And if its Right than accept by clicking "Right" Sign and also upvote.

Answer (score 0):

From the modulesgarden base tab, select plugins/slider

create 2 sliders name

crystal_slider_simple  (this is the larger image)
crystal_small_baners   (used for the 2 smaller images)

also the instructions for enabling the theme are not correct,

template should be modulesgarden as advised,
Skin, template, layout  should be crystal

hope this helps